# Raspbian - Getting multiple dynamic IP addresses with Cisco DHCP static pool

Tags: dhcp

I have both static and dynamic DHCP pools configured at Cisco 8xx router. It looks Rpi with Raspbian Stretch gets TWO IPs from different DHCP pools, both attached to wlan0 interface. Non Linux Raspbian clients are not impacted.

ip r: (shows x.102)

```
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0 
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0  metric 303 
192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.**102** metric 303
```

and:

ifconfig: (shows x.116)

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:58:53:16  
          inet addr:192.168.2.**116**  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

First client gets IP 102 from this pool:

```
ip dhcp pool STATIC
 host 192.168.2.102 255.255.255.0
 hardware-address 74da.3858.5316
 default-router 192.168.2.1 
 dns-server 192.168.2.1
```

but after few seconds client gets also Ip from dynamic pool:

```
ip dhcp pool DYNAMIC
 network 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.2.1 
 dns-server 192.168.2.1
```

This is Cisco DHCP debug LOG:

```
May  7 12:45:34.838: DHCPD: Found Manual/Static binding
May  7 12:45:34.846: DHCPD: Sending notification of ASSIGNMENT:
May  7 12:45:34.846:  DHCPD: address 192.168.2.102 mask 255.255.255.0
May  7 12:45:34.846:   DHCPD: htype 1 chaddr 74da.3858.5316
May  7 12:45:34.846:   DHCPD: lease time remaining (secs) = 4294967295
May  7 12:45:34.846: DHCPD: Sending notification of ASSIGNMENT:
May  7 12:45:34.846:  DHCPD: address 192.168.2.102 mask 255.255.255.0
May  7 12:45:34.846:   DHCPD: htype 1 chaddr 74da.3858.5316
May  7 12:45:34.846:   DHCPD: lease time remaining (secs) = 4294967295
a then later:
May  7 12:45:41.973: DHCPD: Seeing if there is an internally specified pool class:
May  7 12:45:41.973:   DHCPD: htype 1 chaddr 74da.3858.5316
May  7 12:45:41.973:   DHCPD: remote id 020a0000c0a8020102000001
May  7 12:45:41.973:   DHCPD: circuit id 00000000
May  7 12:45:41.973: DHCPD: Allocated binding 2322F4F4
May  7 12:45:41.973: DHCPD: Adding binding to radix tree (192.168.2.116)
May  7 12:45:41.973: DHCPD: Adding binding to hash tree
May  7 12:45:41.973: DHCPD: assigned IP address 192.168.2.116 to client 0174.da38.5853.16.
May  7 12:45:41.973: DHCPD: Sending notification of DISCOVER:
May  7 12:45:41.973:   DHCPD: htype 1 chaddr 74da.3858.5316
```

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: what is "Non Linux Raspbian"? Raspbian is linux, so how can it be not linux?

Comment: Looks only Rpi devices with Raspbian are affected. Win/other OS not.

Comment: I don't see that the `wlan0` interface has two ip addresses. You show that it has only `192.168.2.116`. I don't know the log of your router and how it works with static and dynamic pool but as far as I can see there is only one time `assigned ip address 192.168.2.116 to client 0174.da38.5853.16`. The ip address `192.168.2.102` seems only to be an offer the raspi does not accept. Maybe it's a configuration issue of your dhcp server. It should be `authoritative` for your network. What ip addresses are in the DYNAMIC pool? Does it also contain the address `192.168.2.102`?

Comment: This is actually very strange, because ifconfig shows different ip addr, then ip r. However both IPs are really attached - provided from DHCP server and both are reachable by SSH and ping. DYNAMIC pool has IP range x.120-x.254 available.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be resolved. In official Raspbian Stretch image there are multiple DHCP clients installed and enabled. Both dhcpcd5 and isc-dhcp-client are active and asking dhcp server for lease. Very annoying setup in default Raspbian image. Hope it helps to someone else. Solution: apt-get remove dhcpcd5.